# Rails - SendGrid - invalid response error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sendgrid

I'm using SendGrid for my Rails App on Heroku.  I tested the process of signing up.  I saw the email get created and sent in SendGrid.  The email showed up in my gmail inbox.  But when I clicked the "Activate" link in the email I get the error below.  After I got the email and clicked the link I noticed that even though I only clicked it a few times a long list of "clicked" activities showed up in sendgrid.  I noticed that each click seemed to generate three "clicked" activities in sendgrid.  don't know if that's a clue or not.

sendgrid.net sent an invalid response.
ERR_INVALID_REDIRECT

Comment: That error looks like a circular redirect issue. Maybe SG may replace your link with a link of their own they use to track clicks, and redirect to yours upon logging the click. Have you tried asking them about it?

Comment: Try in incognito browser once.

Comment: Where is your "activate" link pointed at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your host name is correct in production environment.

*config/environments/production.rb*

> Rails.application.configure do
>       .
>       .
>       host = '**your heroku app**.herokuapp.com'
>       .
>       .
>       end

like this:
 host = 'https://fierce-wave.herokuapp.com'